# How to dispose System.Threading.EventWaitHandle in Mono?

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, mono

The System.Threading.EventWaitHandle type does not contain a definition for 'dispose'.

How am I supposed to dispose of the EventWaitHandle when I want to kill the object in which it is contained? I've been having a serious memory leak problem and I've tried setting the EventWaitHandle to null and the memory leak persists.

Here's my code (I'm using Bob Craven's library, I added only the dispose() method):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Rlc.Cron
{
    public class CronObject
    {
        public delegate void CronEvent(CronObject cronObject);
        public event CronEvent OnCronTrigger;
        public event CronEvent OnStarted;
        public event CronEvent OnStopped;
        public event CronEvent OnThreadAbort;

        private  CronObjectDataContext _cronObjectDataContext;
        private  Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();
        private  object _startStopLock = new object();
        private  EventWaitHandle _wh = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private Thread _thread;
        public bool _isStarted;
        private bool _isStopRequested;
        private DateTime _nextCronTrigger;

        public Guid Id { get { return _id; } }
        public object Object { get { return _cronObjectDataContext.Object; } }
        public DateTime LastTigger { get { return _cronObjectDataContext.LastTrigger; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CronObject"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cronObjectDataContext">The cron object data context.</param>
        public CronObject(CronObjectDataContext cronObjectDataContext)
        {
            if (cronObjectDataContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cronObjectDataContext");
            }
            if (cronObjectDataContext.Object == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("cronObjectDataContext.Object");
            }
            if (cronObjectDataContext.CronSchedules == null || cronObjectDataContext.CronSchedules.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("cronObjectDataContext.CronSchedules");
            }
            _cronObjectDataContext = cronObjectDataContext;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool Start()
        {
            lock (_startStopLock)
            {
                // Can't start if already started.
                //
                if (_isStarted)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                _isStarted = true;
                _isStopRequested = false;

                // This is a long running process. Need to run on a thread
                //  outside the thread pool.
                //
                _thread = new Thread(ThreadRoutine);
                _thread.Start();
            }

            // Raise the started event.
            //
            if(OnStarted != null)
            {
                OnStarted(this);
            }

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool Stop()
        {
            lock (_startStopLock)
            {
                // Can't stop if not started.
                //
                if (!_isStarted)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                _isStarted = false;
                _isStopRequested = true;

                // Signal the thread to wake up early
                //
                _wh.Set();

                // Wait for the thread to join.
                //
                if(!_thread.Join(5000))
                {
                    _thread.Abort();

                    // Raise the thread abort event.
                    //
                    if(OnThreadAbort != null)
                    {
                        OnThreadAbort(this);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Raise the stopped event.
            //
            if(OnStopped != null)
            {
                OnStopped(this);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void dispose(){
            this.Stop ();
            this.OnCronTrigger = null;
            this.OnStarted=null;
            this.OnStopped=null;
            this.OnThreadAbort=null;

            this._cronObjectDataContext=null;
            this._startStopLock = null;
            this._wh = null;
            this._thread=null;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Cron object thread routine.
        /// </summary>
        private void ThreadRoutine()
        {
            // Continue until stop is requested.
            //
            while(!_isStopRequested)
            {
                // Determine the next cron trigger
                //
                DetermineNextCronTrigger(out _nextCronTrigger);

                TimeSpan sleepSpan = _nextCronTrigger - DateTime.Now;
                if(sleepSpan.TotalMilliseconds < 0)
                {
                    // Next trigger is in the past. Trigger the right away.
                    //
                    sleepSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
                }

                // Wait here for the timespan or until I am triggered
                //  to wake up.
                //
                if(!_wh.WaitOne(sleepSpan))
                {
                    // Timespan is up...raise the trigger event
                    //
                    if(OnCronTrigger != null)
                    {
                        OnCronTrigger(this);
                    }

                    // Update the last trigger time.
                    //
                    _cronObjectDataContext.LastTrigger = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines the next cron trigger.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nextTrigger">The next trigger.</param>
        private void DetermineNextCronTrigger(out DateTime nextTrigger)
        {
            nextTrigger = DateTime.MaxValue;
            foreach (CronSchedule cronSchedule in _cronObjectDataContext.CronSchedules)
            {
                DateTime thisTrigger;
                if(cronSchedule.GetNext(LastTigger, out thisTrigger))
                {
                    if (thisTrigger < nextTrigger)
                    {
                        nextTrigger = thisTrigger;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ~CronObject(){
            Console.WriteLine ("===================CRONOBJECT DESTROYED!!===============");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `EventWaitHandle` implements `IDisposable`. There should be a `Dispose` method. I'm not sure it was implemented as explicit interface implementation, but it implements.

Comment: Where did you see it? I'm looking at https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/EventWaitHandle.cs and there is no IDisposable there

Comment: @joesmith: in the parent class WaitHandle

Comment: It says the method is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: that's impossible, the method is public in WaitHandle class. What version of mono are you using?

Comment: I have Mono.CSharp 4.0.0.0

Comment: That's not your mono version. Anyway, as far as I can tell it has been added back in `2.8`. You may be running an older version, in which case upgrade. Alternatively, you can call [Close()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is what `Dispose` does too.